# Made of the author of a section

Tags: tables

I'm making a report where a lot of people have written a part/chapter/section and I would like to indicate the author of each part/chapter/section beside the title.

I would appreciate if it's on the other side of the page and if it is in italic, to really see the difference between title and author.

I don't really know how to add this kind of argument for the chapter/part/section.

If i'm not clear enought don't hesitate to ask me more indications

Thank you for your help !

Quentin

Comment: Wher would you like to see the authors'names? In the header of each page?